# Images getting overlapped in Canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I'm using a canvas tag to display an image uploaded by the user. To change an image a user has to just upload another image file and so the old image in canvas is replaced by new image.

I'm able to do this in normal Javascript but when I try the same thing in Angular I'm facing problems. Instead of replacing the old image the new image is being displayed on top of the old one.

**HTML Code**..

```
  <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <script src="js/exif.js"></script>
   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="item_image" id="image_label" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add Id Proof</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="ifile" ng-model="ifile">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <canvas id="panel" ng-model="panel" width="300" height="300" style=" display: table;margin: 0 25%;margin-bottom:10px;"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Angular Js Code**..

```
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

     //beginning of image display
var canvasCtx = document.getElementById("panel").getContext("2d");

$('#ifile').change(function(event) {
    EXIF.getData(event.target.files[0], function() {
    exif = EXIF.getAllTags(this);

    picOrientation = exif.Orientation;
    });

    this.imageFile = event.target.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =  function(event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            drawImage(img);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageFile);
});

var drawImage = function(img) {
    canvasCtx.width = 300;
    canvasCtx.height = 300;

    if(img.width>img.height){                                               //Landscape Image 
        canvasCtx.width = 300;
        canvasCtx.height = 300 / img.width * img.height;
    } else {                                                                  //Portrait Image
        canvasCtx.width = 300 / img.height * img.width;
        canvasCtx.height = 300;
    } 

    if (picOrientation==2){
        canvasCtx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1,canvasCtx.width, 0);
    }
    if (picOrientation==3){
        canvasCtx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1,canvasCtx.width, canvasCtx.height);
    }
    if (picOrientation==4){
        canvasCtx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvasCtx.height );
    }
    if (picOrientation==5){
        canvasCtx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (picOrientation==6){
        canvasCtx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, canvasCtx.height , 0);
    }
    if (picOrientation==7){
        canvasCtx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, canvasCtx.height , canvasCtx.width);
    }
    if (picOrientation==8){
        canvasCtx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, canvasCtx.width);
    }

    canvasCtx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvasCtx.width, canvasCtx.height);
    image_url = canvasCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
}           
//end of image display
     });
```

Output I'm getting when uplaoding a new image..

[image: Overlapping image]

As you can see above the bat image is being drawn on top of the chair image instead of uploading it.I'm not able to get the new image replace the old one in canvas tag while uploading.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help. Try,

```
 style="position:fixed;"
```